# Rename directory

Tags: wordpress, tags, directory

I have a question. 
I would like to have a directory named like this : `http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/people/matt`.
For the moment, what I want to do, works with `http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/tag/matt`.

Anyone can help me ? Please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are more talking about the category name than a directory.
If so just go to your `Settings > Permalinks` in the `Optional` section change your `Category base` tag `cat` (the default one) to `people`

Nicolas.

Comment: Not category, I found it's a new custom type ! :p

Comment: Yeah but that's a different purpose and from the few information I can read here I had no ideas you wanted to create custom types and therefore wanted different URLs for each (I guess it's what you meant by custom type and your previous question).